# To know the logic behind it

Tags: java

is there anybody who explain me this coding

```
public class FunctionCall {

  public static void funct1 () {
    System.out.println ("Inside funct1");
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    int val;
    System.out.println ("Inside main");
    funct1();
    System.out.println ("About to call funct2");
    val = funct2(8);
    System.out.println ("funct2 returned a value of " + val);
    System.out.println ("About to call funct2 again");
    val = funct2(-3);
    System.out.println ("funct2 returned a value of " + val);
  }

  public static int funct2 (int param) {
    System.out.println ("Inside funct2 with param " + param);
    return param * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you need explanation on?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class FunctionCall {//a public class

  public static void funct1 () { /a static method which returns nothing void
    System.out.println ("Inside funct1");
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {//main method
    int val;//int variable declaration
    System.out.println ("Inside main");//printing on console
    funct1();//calling static method
    System.out.println ("About to call funct2");////printing on console
    val = funct2(8);//calling static method which returns int and assigning it to val variable
    System.out.println ("funct2 returned a value of " + val);//printing on console
    System.out.println ("About to call funct2 again");//printing on console
    val = funct2(-3);////calling static method which returns int and assigning it to val 
    System.out.println ("funct2 returned a value of " + val);//printing on console
  }

  public static int funct2 (int param) {
    System.out.println ("Inside funct2 with param " + param);
    return param * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me the best book of android (TO STUDY)

Comment: the question your posted is not related to android , its simple core java, if you need assistance about android please go ahead and make new question

Answer (score 0):

Of course, but where is the problem?

There are 2 static methods

```
public static void funct1 () {
  System.out.println ("Inside funct1"); 
}
```

and

```
public static int funct2 (int param) {
  System.out.println ("Inside funct2 with param " + param); 
  return param * 2; 
}
```

The output on console will be (If I don't made a calculation mistake):

```
Inside main
Inside funct1
About to call funct2
Inside funct2 with param 8
funct2 returned a value of 16
About to call funct2 again
Inside funct2 with param -3
funct2 returned a value of -6
```

It starts with the main, then it enters the funct1 once; then it calles func2 with 8 and another time with -3

Comment: sir can you told me what is the output of this program1: class Blanks { 
2:     public static void main(String[] arguments) { 
3:         System.out.println("The " + arguments[0] 
4:             + " " + arguments[1] + " fox " 
5:             + "jumped over the " 
6:             + arguments[2] + " dog."); 
7:     } 
8: }

Comment: It's difficult to read like that, however it seems that this program takes 3 arguments and depending on that it prints out one sentence